# IntelliJ IDEA using way too much memory

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm new to programming, and i'm currently using Python. The courses i'm following insist on me using the community version of intellij. I have an i5 laptop with 8gb ram. 
I haven't even typed anything into the program, i literally just opened it, clean slate, and it's using 686mb of ram. I notice that after typing in simple programs and continuously checking the program by running it, it goes over a gig of memory usage. Even though the whole machine doesn't go above 50% physical memory usage.

My machine starts stalling, like mouse pausing, programs are not maximizing and minmizing etc. Does anyone else experienced this? Is there anything I can do to cut the memory usage down? I literally just want the GUI and error correction and to be able to run the program, I don't need all the other stuff it seems to use.

Comment: if i in range(Julian's edit):

Comment: Please open new issue on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA attaching log folder zipped ("Help | Show Log in...") and Memory snapshot: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Answer (score 8):

You can check the plugin settings and turn those unnecessary plugins off. I tried this and reduced about 2G+ memory.